# Could we get a logo for our stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's nothing too important but I think it'd be nice if we had some logo/picture to identify with. I wouldn't really consider myself an artist but I'd be willing to put up a few designs if people were interested.

Is this something we as a community are interested in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beta sites, such as Vi & Vim, do not get designs until after graduation (aka becoming a full SE site, removing the "beta" label). The logo and site icon are part of the site's design.

As for "when will Vi & Vim graduate, then?," the answer is pretty much "it'll graduate when it graduates." There is... almost never a clear timeframe for graduation; it's decided by the Powers That Be.

Comment: The Craft CMS beta Stack exchange seems to have a logo.

Comment: I believe that the current de-facto graduation requirements are roughly "consistently generates about ten quality questions/day". This site is roughly at five/six a day.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that our site wasn't or shouldn't be in beta. I was only noticing that the Craft CMS Stack exchange, although still in beta, appears to have a logo on http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#

Comment: @Tumbler41 There are a few exceptions for commercial products. I would assume that StackExchange is being paid to put the logo there (like "sponsored tags" on Stack Overflow), or perhaps it's for historical reasons. Not sure. But in general, beta sites don't get a logo.